# SQL Server - Query. How do I split a column into 2 where the ID of rows are duplicated?

Tags: sql-server, join, duplicates

I'm pulling a report together and have joined many tables; in this case, the table I'm trying to pull data from has duplicate ID's with multiple (2) values by each ID, as if they should be in 2 columns:

```
ID    Position   Caption   Value
---   --------   -------   -----
143   1          Company   QW
143   2          Invoice   Long Service
144   1          Company   IT
144   2          Invoice   Complete Kit
145   1          Company   OD
145   2          Invoice   Foundation Leaflets
146   1          Company   BIRT
146   2          Invoice   TASIT
```

Currently I've joined this to another table with ID, as expected it now duplicates every line of data, when ideally I'd like to make the ID joined distinctly and show the data like this:

```
ID    Company   Invoice
---   -------   -----
143   QW        Long Service
144   IT        Complete Kit
145   OD        Foundation Leaflets
146   BIRT      TASIT
```

This is my current code, which produces 2 columns but keeps the duplicate rows...

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN IR.Caption = 'Owning Company' THEN Value ELSE NULL END AS OwningCompany,
CASE WHEN IR.Caption = 'Invoice Summary' THEN Value ELSE NULL END AS InvoiceSummary
FROM Invoices AS I INNER JOIN
InvoiceReferences AS IR ON IR.InvoiceID = I.ID
WHERE        (I.InvoiceStatus = '1')
```

Gives me these results:

```
OwningCompany   InvoiceSummary
DT                  NULL
NULL            Guide to Public Sector Tendering
BIRT            NULL
NULL            Agency
BIRT            NULL
NULL            food-catering
```

I'd like the results to be like the following:

```
OwningCompany   InvoiceSummary
DT              Guide to Public Sector Tendering
BIRT            Agency
BIRT            food-catering
```

Thank you

Note, I'm more familiar with MySQL format than SQL Server Management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.ID
,b.Value Company
,c.Value Invoice
FROM Invoices a
JOIN InvoiceReferences b
    ON a.ID = b.InvoiceID
    AND b.Caption = 'Owning Company'
JOIN InvoiceReferences c
    ON a.ID = c.InvoiceID
    AND c.Caption = 'Invoice Summary'
WHERE (a.InvoiceStatus = '1')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! Just to note, I didn't need to use DISTINCT in this case (The results were the same with and without)

Comment: Sure, I wasn't sure if the data in the original table may cause duplication. Good to know that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.  This assumes that every company ID also has an invoice ID.  If that's not true, you may have to do a different join and perhaps use something like coalesce.

```
;WITH InvoiceSummaries
AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value AS InvoiceSummary 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Caption = 'Invoice Summary'
)
,OwningCompanies
AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value AS OwningCompany
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Caption = 'Owning Company'
)
SELECT a.ID,b.OwningCompany, a.InvoiceSummary
FROM InvoiceSummaries a
INNER JOIN OwningCompanies b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You really just need a `group by` and a dummy aggregation. I think I'm grouping on the right column if I followed your queries right. I removed the `else null`s since you don't strictly need them but really just to get rid of the scroll bar in the code window.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CASE WHEN IR.Caption = 'Owning Company'  THEN Value END) AS OwningCompany,
    MIN(CASE WHEN IR.Caption = 'Invoice Summary' THEN Value END) AS InvoiceSummary
FROM
    Invoices AS I INNER JOIN
    InvoiceReferences AS IR
        ON IR.InvoiceID = I.ID
WHERE
    I.InvoiceStatus = '1'
GROUP BY
    I.ID
```